# Managing SQL authentication credentials in a web app for multi-tenancy with database per user model

Tags: sql, sql-server, security, multi-tenant, saas

Let's assume that you have a B2B SAAS web application.

If you are using database-per-tenant approach, should you use the same SQL authentication credentials for all the tenants while connecting to SQL from your web application or should you ideally separate them and randomly generate passwords (or perhaps even user-names)?

Which option is more ideal? Is it really a security-concern for a cloud-hosted environment?

Companies, especially enterprises are usually concerned about security but I am not sure if it would be over-engineering to create different passwords for every-one.

Comment: Interesting question. I am inclined to say this is overkill. Strictly from a webdev perspecitive, separate passwords for each DB would not be necessary or give you any greater security. From a DevOps/systems perspective, there might be a need or desire to do this. Let's say you wanted security with your systems group where you didn't want everyone to have access to all DB's. That might be an argument for this kind of architecture.